# Create a PowerShell script that would get the last 30 days history logon of Domain Admin member

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to write a Power Shell script that would do the following:
- If the user is member of (Domain admins) get me the last 30 days history logon of this user in any Domain joined computer.

I created something now but it still lacks a lot as it reads the security events on the Domain controller and brings the users,time and matches them with the Domain admin group as in the attached screenshot

I would appreciate if someone can help me evolve this script into something useful

```
$Rusers = Get-WinEvent  -Computer dc02 -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 50 |
 `   select @{N='User';E={$_.Properties[1].Value}},TimeCreated

$DAUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins"

Foreach ($DAUser in $DAUsers){
$DomainUser = $DAUser.SamAccountName

foreach ($Ruser in $Rusers){
$RAUser = $Ruser.User

If ($RAUser -match $DomainUser){
Write-Host $Ruser is domain admin }
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}
```

Comment: Unless your domain is tiny, then the security logs will roll over well before 30 days. Increasing the log size will make searching very slow. You're better off running a scheduled task to grab the logons every day, just for that day and logging them to another file such as a csv. Don't forget also that you'd have to look at EVERY domain controller - normal logon events are not replicated between DCs.

Comment: These are very useful information, Thank you! I will take that into account but still needs to adjust this script to at least make it useful per day to get the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get domain admin user list
$DomainAdminList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins'
# Get all Domain Controller names
$DomainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Sort-Object HostName
# EventID
$EventID = '4672'
#
# Get only last 24hrs
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
# Limit log event search for testing as this will take a LONG time on most domains
# For normal running, this will have to be set to zero
$MaxEvent = 50  

# Loop through Dcs
$DALogEvents = $DomainControllers | ForEach-Object {
    $CurDC = $_.HostName
    Write-Host "`nSearching $CurDC logs..."
    Get-WinEvent  -Computer $CurDC -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=$EventID;StartTime = $Date} -MaxEvents $MaxEvent |`
    Where-Object { $_.Properties[1].Value -in $DomainAdminList.SamAccountName } |`
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{SamAccountName = $_.Properties[1].Value;Time = $_.TimeCreated;LogonEventLocation = $CurDC}
    }
}
```

All the Domain Admin logon events should now be in `$DALogEvents`

You'll need to group results by name, then export to a file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I apologize I was not clear enough. The kind of information I am looking for is pertaining to users who have been utilized for services e.g. (SQL reporting Services, Or Sccm Service ..etc )

Answer (score 0):

[image]Thanks a lot for your help, I apologize I was not clear enough. The kind of information I am looking for is pertaining to users who have been utilized for services e.g. (SQL reporting Services, Or Sccm Service ..etc )

This script does what I want but it doesn't run only for domain admin users, it runs for everyone basically and not sure if there's a limit to the time/date.

Is it possible to adjust it to let it run against Domain Admin users for 30 days and print information like. Source IP, User, Target Dc, Date?

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4624 |
  ForEach-Object {
    # translate the raw data into a new object
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Time = $_.TimeGenerated
        User = "{0}\{1}" -f $_.ReplacementStrings[5], $_.ReplacementStrings[6]
        Type = $_.ReplacementStrings[10]
        "Source Network Address" = $_.ReplacementStrings[18]
        Target = $_.ReplacementStrings[19]
    }
  }
```

Comment: As I mentioned - it's highly unlikely your DC logs go back 30 days. there's a date field in my script, just set it as required. You can get any information from the event you need - again just amend output as required,.

Comment: Man, you rock! Thanks a lot I managed to get what I want by changing and adding some values in the pscustomobject.

Answer (score 0):

I've added couple more of custom objects to get the result that I needed. I think turning this into a function would be great tool to use for auditing.

Thanks a lot to you @Specialist

```
# Get domain admin user list
$DomainAdminList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins'
# Get all Domain Controller names
$DomainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Sort-Object HostName
# EventID
$EventID = '4624'
#
# Get only last 24hrs
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
# Limit log event search for testing as this will take a LONG time on most domains
# For normal running, this will have to be set to zero
$MaxEvent = 100

# Loop through Dcs
$DALogEvents = $DomainControllers | ForEach-Object {
    $CurDC = $_.HostName
    Write-Host "`nSearching $CurDC logs..."
    Get-WinEvent  -ComputerName $CurDC -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=$EventID;StartTime = $Date} -MaxEvents $MaxEvent |`
    Where-Object { $_.Properties[5].Value -in $DomainAdminList.SamAccountName } |`
    ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{SourceIP = $_.Properties[18].Value; SamAccountName = $_.Properties[5].Value;Time = $_.TimeCreated;LogonEventLocation = $CurDC}
    }
}
$DALogEvents
```